# Lectura de cadenas en c++

Tags: c++

Soy estudiante y tengo un problema con la lectura de caracteres en c++, al momento de seleccionar la opción A en el case el programa salta el ingreso de la cadena de caracteres y al ingresar los datos faltantes no imprime de forma correcta los datos ingresados

```
    do{
        cout<<"\n   Introduzca opcion (A-F): ";
        cin>>opcion;
    }
    while ( opcion < 'A' || opcion > 'F' );
    
    switch (opcion){
        case 'A':
            cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre: ";
            cin.getline(nombre,50,'\n');
            cout<<"Ingresa tu direccion: ";
            cin.getline(nombre,50,'\n');
            cout<<"Ingresa la fecha: ";
            cin.getline(nombre,20,'\n');
            cout<<"Ingresa el monto: ";
            cin.getline(nombre,20,'\n');
            cout<<"\nSu nombre es: "<<nombre;
            cout<<"\nSu direccion es: "<<direccion;
            cout<<"\nLa fecha es: "<<fecha;
            cout<<"\nEl monto a pagar es: $"<<monto<<endl;                                                              
            break;
    }       
} while ( opcion != 'G'  );
```

}

Comment: Mira por que tu codigo sea un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) De ese modo se nos hara mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Parece que estás asignando el valor a la misma variable "nombre", a menos que sea lo que quieras hacer, deberías cambiarlo para que en cada getline recibir el valor a la variable que debe ser.

Answer (score 0):

1.te recomiendo usar un struct tipo

```
        struct opciones{
        string nombre;
        string direccion;
        string fecha;
        float monto;

        };
```

2.y en tu switch poner
3.declarar variable de tipo opcion

```
        opciones datos;
        cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre: ";
        cin>>datos.nombre;
        cout<<"Ingresa tu direccion: ";
        cin>>datos.direccion;
        cout<<"Ingresa la fecha: ";
        cin>>datos.fecha;
        cout<<"Ingresa el monto: ";
        cin>>datos.monto;
        cout<<"\nSu nombre es: "<<datos.nombre;
        cout<<"\nSu direccion es: "<<datos.direccion;
        cout<<"\nLa fecha es: "<<datos.fecha;
        cout<<"\nEl monto a pagar es: $"<<datos.monto<<endl;                                                              
        break;
```

recordando incluir la libreria string